Datetime type to be used in SQL Plus
I am working on SQL Plus Oracle Database 21c Express Edition 21.0.0.0 Version 21.3.0.0
I am making a table Post, out of which one attribute requires the date and time of posting. I have tried using the types datetime and timestamp as different sources on the internet point me in different directions, and in both cases SQL throws an error "invalid datatype".
create table Post(
post_id integer primary key,
title varchar(60),
post_time timestamp,
content text,
username varchar(20),
foreign key(username) references Users(username)
);

Could someone please tell me what needs to be modified, I would also prefer that the datetime be inserted in the format 'DD-MM-YYY hh:mm:ss' if possible.

text is not listed as a valid datatype in the documentation for Oracle 21c. From where did you get the idea to the contrary, or the notion that this error has something to do with your date/time field?

timestamp is a valid data type; datetime is not; date is also valid and includes the time down to seconds. But text is not a valid data type in Oracle, and it is that column causing the error in the code you posted. Rather than looking at different sources on the internet, which is probably giving you information for different databases, look at the Oracle documentation. Dates and timestamps also do not have an inherent format in the database.

DATE is what you are looking for. Includes date and time, no milliseconds.

SQL*Plus is a command-line tool for batch scripts and quick commands. You may be using it, but it's not relevant to your question.


Could someone please tell me what needs to be modified

TEXT is not a valid Oracle data-type. Use a CLOB.
create table Post(
  post_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  title     VARCHAR2(60),         -- VARCHAR2 not VARCHAR
  post_time DATE,                 -- DATE has time component
  content   CLOB,                 -- Text is not valid, use CLOB
  username,                       -- Do not need a data type as it will inherit
                                  -- the data type from the referenced column.
  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES Users(username)
);

Note: As well as DATE (which always has a time component in Oracle) you could also use TIMESTAMP(0) as a timestamp with 0 digits of fractional seconds.

I would also prefer that the datetime be inserted in the format 'DD-MM-YYY hh:mm:ss' if possible.

In Oracle:

A DATE data type is a binary data-type consisting of 7-bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second.
A TIMESTAMP data type is a binary data-type consisting of 7-13 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second and 0-6 bytes representing fractional seconds.

Both a binary data-types and ALWAYS have those components and are NEVER stored in any particular human-readable format.
If you want to display the date in a particular human-readable format then use:
SELECT TO_CHAR(post_time, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS post_time
FROM   post

to display it in your desired format.
If you want to INSERT data in that format then use TO_DATE to convert from a string in your expected format to a DATE:
INSERT INTO post (post_time)
VALUES (TO_DATE('09-04-2024 12:34:56', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

